# How to test endpoint in org.apache.camel.CamelContext for invalid credentials or invalid URL before using the CamelContext.start() for routing?

Tags: java, routes, ftp, apache-camel

I have been using **ApacheCamel** to connect to ftp/sftp but when ever the credentials (of the ftp/sftp) is invalid I see that camel doesn't throw any exception when I call CamelContext.start() method to route. So is there any methods available to test the credentials of the endpoint before calling the start method or any workaround which I can implement before connecting to ftp/sftp.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about a [Camel FTP](https://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html) **producer**. I assume it does not connect to the remote server **as long as there is no message to route**.

Since the component is not doing what you want on route start, you have the option of implementing a [**Route Policy**](https://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html). The base class `RoutePolicySupport` gives you a good start.

In the Route Policy you can **implement callbacks like `onStart`** and add your custom logic that is executed when the given event occurs.